# POSTGRESQL: use EXCEPT in each GROUP BY

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE rqrd  
(p_id INTEGER, 
co_id INTEGER);

INSERT INTO rqrd VALUES 
    (1, 100), 
    (1, 800), 
    (2, 100),
    (2, 800), 
    (3, 100), 
    (3, 800), 
    (3, 900);



CREATE TABLE completed  
(p_id INTEGER, 
co_id INTEGER);

INSERT INTO completed VALUES 
    (1, 100), 
    (1, 800), 
    (2, 100),
    (3, 100), 
    (3, 800), 
    (3, 900);
```

How can I return rows from `completed` in case that in each `p_id` group in `rqrd` there's no more rows for that `p_id` (confusing enough!!)
I mean I want:

```
(1, 100), 
(1, 800)
```

and

```
(3, 100), 
(3, 800), 
(3, 900);
```

from `completed` to show up in the result because there's no more rows for `p_id` = 1 or 3 in `rqrd`. 
But (2, 100) doesn't come into result because we have:

(2, 800),

in `rqrd` table as well.

Comment: So, you're wanting 1) all rows from Completed 2) per p_id, except where 3) 1 or more rows exist in rqrd for that p_id that 4) aren't in Completed?

Comment: exactly! I want all 4 conditions that you mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I totally understand the question, but maybe something like this:

```
select *
  from completed
  where p_id not in (

     select r.p_id
       from rqrd r
       left join completed c on (c.p_id = r.p_id and c.co_id = r.co_id)
       where c.p_id is null

  )
;
```

The sub-query looks at all the `rqrd` records `p_id, co_id` and looks for such pairs that do not exist in `completed`.  If such a combination does not exist, then that `p_id` is not valid and all such `p_id` records are filtered from the `completed` query.